# Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found in (Xcode 8.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
```

I installed the Firebase using Cocoapods and implemented Facebook login in Xcode 8 beta 4. The app and Facebook login was working fine in Xcode 8. After I had updated to Xcode 8.1 beta, the Facebook login is `not being redirecting automatically` to the login page as usual.

According to the Log:

```
FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found. Please add the handler into your App Delegate. Class: pushlite.AppDelegate
```

I also found out the application function with openURL not being called as below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    print("Handler Called")
    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    // Add any custom logic here.
    return handled
}
```

Would someone direct me in the right way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application

Comment: noted with thanks !

Answer (score 1):

i had just solved this issue for iOS 10.1 by going into Facebook iOS guide and **using the latest application openURL from Facebook and rebuild.** It is working like charm again. Have no idea how its solved but hope it may help other which in iOS 10.1 with Facebooklogin.